# Why am i getting a line break on this AJAX response?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am sending an ajax call via the following:

```
var response = sendViaAjax(str,'Session/delete_From_Session_AJAX.php') ;

    alert('response:|'+response+'|') ;

    if(response == 'complete') {//returns complete if the table was not to be rewritten
        el = this ;
        while(el.tagName !== 'TR'){
            el = el.parentNode ;
            alert(el.tagName) ;
        }
        removeChildren(el) ;
        removeElement(el) ;
    }else if(response!= 'complete') {
        alert(response+' is not equal to complete') ;
        parseHTMLStr(response,window.cur_tbl,1,0,0) ;       
    }
```

The relevant code from delete_Session... is

```
if( isset($_POST['REWRITE']) ) {
    include("return_Tabular_Data.php") ;
}else{
    echo 'complete' ;
}
```

The alert I am getting from the formatted string is:

```
complete
         is not equal to complete
```

Something must be added but I cannot find where. I use this function extensively and have never had a similar issue.

The only place I modify the response in sendViaAjax is

```
var RESPONSE = xmlhttp.responseText ;
RESPONSE = RESPONSE.replace(/^\s+/, '');
return RESPONSE ;
```

Comment: the condition in code "}else if(response!= 'complete') {" seems unnecessary, it could be just "}else {"

Comment: You are right for sure. I added that just trying to figure out what was going on with this line break.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have whitespace after your closing `?>` tag on the server-side?

Ideally, when using AJAX you want to `exit` specifically when you want output to end. Or you can just not put `?>`, since it's optional at the end of the file.

Comment: Sho nuff. Thanks. Those closing tags have caused more than a few issues for me.